# Junos Pulse Crashing on El Capitan (10.11), Causing Keychain Issues?

Tags: keychain, vpn, macos

Whenever I attempt to start a VPN Connection with Junos Pulse (Version 5.0.11) on El Capitan it freezes midway through connecting and my login keychain becomes inaccessible to any other apps. The only way I've found to restore my keychain and restart Pulse is to restart. Killing Junos Pulse and the PulseTray processes in Activity Monitor seems to have no effect.

Comment: tried to update to the latest PulseSecure Client Version 5.1.5, but still having exact same issue as described above.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I had the exact same issue. Basically, this happens only if you enable the checkbox "Save Settings" at the username/password prompt in Junos Pulse. If you do not enable this checkbox, it should not freeze at the next connection attempt.
Pulsesecure have released the software version 5.1R5.1 build 61437, where this issue has been fixed (I tested it today and it is working fine). I hope this helps.

Comment: yann, where can I download the new version? Thanks.

Comment: This seems to have fixed it for me.

Comment: Awesome. I was wondering if that would work, but I've been in the middle of a project and didn't want to have to reboot, so I've just been re-adding the connection profile every time.

Comment: Hi Colin, you can download it directly on the pulsesecure website: https://www.pulsesecure.net/support/. Of course, you'll need to have a support contract for your pulse secure products.

Comment: just get 5.1R5.1 build 61437 and works like a charm, finally!

Comment: Did you have to do anything to fix up your Keychain afterwards? I cannot install 5.1R5.1 because my admin user appears to have lost admin rights/cannot unlock preferences pages.

Comment: To get an existing connection to work again, right-clicking the connection and hitting 'Forget Saved Details' worked.

Answer (score 2):

So far the only workaround I've found is to remove the connection profile in Junos Pulse and re-add it, which avoids any attempt to access the keychain. I'd be happy if there was a more long term solution.

Comment: I'm seeing this exact same issue. If I quit Junos before I try to connect, no keychain issues. Otherwise, all sorts of Keychain issues. Removing and reading the the connection per @avaleske's suggestion worked perfectly for me.

Comment: I can confirm that removing and adding the connection without saving settings works for me, that's using v5.0.7.